# Compare and obtain intervals intersections between rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data base like the following.

```
pos1<-c(5,15,25,40,80,5,18,22,38,84,5,16,50,92,31,50,20,30,50,70,27,50,60,50,90,20,40)
pos2<-c(10,17,30,42,90,10,20,24,42,87,10,19,52,100,40,70,25,32,60,90,30,60,71,60,100,25,50)
chr<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
n<-c(25,65,78,56,35,78,58,98,14,25,65,85,98,74,20,36,48,98,52,69,21,47,53,10,12,37,82)
pop<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D")
data<-data.frame(pos1,pos2,chr,pop,n)
```

Position 1 and position 2 designed the start and end point of an interval for each chr and population. My intention is to obtain which interval intersects between pops A, B and C (not D) and which intervals are unique for each population.

So, for the unique intervals I would have an outcome data.frame like the following:

```
pos1.u<-c(25,50,92,20,30,27,90)
pos2.u<-c(30,52,100,25,32,30,100)
chr.u<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
pop.u<-c("A","B","C","A","A","B","C")
n.u<-c(78,98,74,48,98,21,12)
data.u<-data.frame(pos1.u,pos2.u,chr.u,pop.u,n.u)
```

And for the intervals that intersects between those 3 populations a data.frame like the following:

```
pos1.c<-c(5,15,40,80,5,38,85,5,16,50,70,50,60,50)
pos2.c<-c(10,17,42,90,10,42,87,10,19,60,90,60,71,60)
chr.c<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
pop.c<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","A","A","B","B","C")
n.c<-c(25,65,56,35,78,14,25,65,85,52,69,47,53,10)
data.c<-data.frame(pos1.c,pos2.c,chr.c,pop.c,n.c)
```

I don't know how to write a script that does precisely this, can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "intersects between those 3 populations"? Best I can tell, there are only two combinations of `pos1`, `pos2`, and `chr` that occur in A, B, and C: 5, 10, and 1, and 50, 60, and 2.

Comment: Those are segments that have complete intersection. But Im interested in every segment that overlaps. Perhaps I should use overlaping more than intersecting... sorry. so I want to find every segment that overlaps and every segment that does not overlaps! Thanks for your question! I hope you can help me further...

Comment: And by "overlap", you mean that some part of the sequence starting at `pos1` and ending at `pos2` for a particular combination `chr` and `pop` also appears in at least one sequence with the same value of `chr` but a different value for `pop`, right?

Comment: Yes, but, one clarification. chr must be the same, compare the chr=1 in pop A with chr=1 in pop B and so on... But the chr needs to be the same. (indeed chr means chromosome, these are positions in the genome). Thanks! and sorry perhaps I didnt explain my question nicely...

Comment: Have a look at the `intervals` package, which includes functions to identify overlaps and intersections.  I think you need to be more specific on what you are looking for, as a three-way comparison (between A B and C) contains a lot of potential combinations, and it is not clear exactly what output you want.  Also, are the values always integers?  And do you have open or closed intervals (i.e. are the end points included) - so, does (5,10) overlap with (10,15) or not?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of potential combinations. And I want to get the outcomes in two data.frame one for the segments that are common and other for the segments that are unique in each pop, by chr. Values are always integers since are possitions in the genome. End points are not included (close intervals, so (5,10) does not overlap with (10,15)). I already check "intervals" but I dont now how I can apply it to my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the 'unique' df the set of intervals in each category that are not overlapped by any interval in either of the other categories, or is the 'common' df the set of intervals in each category that are overlapped by at least one interval in each of the other categories?  Whichever of these is correct, presumably the other df is the set of entries not in the above.

Comment: Yes, both definitions of "unique" and "common" are correct. So the combination of both unique df and common df should be the complete df. Categories meaning pop (within a particular Chr). Thanks again! I wouldnt imagine that my explanation was that bad!

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code does what you ask for, although it produces different results from yours - so please check it carefully!  The discrepancy I think lies in the definition of open and closed intervals.  The following assumes that neither end point is included, whereas I suspect this might not be what you mean (otherwise (15,18) and (17,19) would not count as overlapping, as there is no integer value that falls in both).  So you might need to adjust the open/closed definitions below.

```
pos1<-c(5,15,25,40,80,5,18,22,38,84,5,16,50,92,31,50,20,30,50,70,27,50,60,50,90,20,40)
pos2<-c(10,17,30,42,90,10,20,24,42,87,10,19,52,100,40,70,25,32,60,90,30,60,71,60,100,25,50)
chr<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
n<-c(25,65,78,56,35,78,58,98,14,25,65,85,98,74,20,36,48,98,52,69,21,47,53,10,12,37,82)
pop<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D")
data<-data.frame(pos1,pos2,chr,pop,n,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(intervals)
data<-data[data$pop!="D",] #remove irrelevant D entries
rownames(data) <- seq_len(nrow(data)) #reset rownames to allow for removed Ds

#set ints as a list of intervals (as required by intervals package)
ints <- tapply(1:nrow(data),data$pop,function(v) 
         Intervals(as.matrix(data[v,c("pos1","pos2")]),
         closed=c(FALSE,FALSE), #this is where you adjust open/closed lower and upper ends of the intervals - TRUE means end value included
         type="Z")) #Z is integers
pops <- unique(data$pop) #unique values of pop
popidx <- lapply(pops,function(x) which(data$pop==x)) #list of indices of these values in data
names(popidx) <- pops

#sets is a df of all pairwise combinations to check
sets <- expand.grid(pops,pops,stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
sets <- sets[sets$Var1!=sets$Var2,]

olap <- lapply(1:nrow(sets),function(i) 
        interval_overlap(ints[[sets$Var1[i]]],ints[[sets$Var2[i]]])) #list of overlaps
olap <- lapply(1:nrow(sets),function(i) {
  df<-as.data.frame(olap[[i]],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df$pos1 <- as.numeric(rownames(df))
  df$pos2 <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(j) popidx[[sets$Var2[i]]][df[j,1][[1]][1]])
  return(df)}) #tidy up as dfs, with correct indices in data (rather than in ints)
olap <- do.call(rbind,olap)[,-1] #join dataframes
olap$olaps <- !is.na(olap$pos2) #identify those with overlaps

#group by unique pos1 and identify max and min no of overlaps with other groups
olap <- data.frame(minoverlap=tapply(olap$olaps,olap$pos1,min),maxoverlap=tapply(olap$olaps,olap$pos1,max))
olap$rowno <- as.numeric(rownames(olap))

uniques <- data[olap$rowno[olap$maxoverlap==0],] #intervals appearing in just one pop
commons <- data[olap$rowno[olap$minoverlap>0],] #intervals with an overlap in all other pops
```

Comment: That's a relief!  I'm sure there must be a more elegant way, though.

Comment: Andrew. I have a question. I have been using this script a little bit modified for long now. And I just figure it out that perhaps the variable "Chr" is not considered. I hope you can help me to just compare intervals within the same “Chr” (in this example 1 and 2). Do I explain myself?

Comment: @Cisco You're right - my script ignores `chr` - I obviously didn't read the comments closely enough, as the question does not mention it. The easiest workaround is perhaps to split the data into chunks by `chr`, and operate on each one separately.  So `datalist <- split(data, data$chr)` will produce a list of dataframes, then you could do `results <- lapply(datalist, foo)` where `foo` is your function to extract `data.u` and/or `data.c` from `data`.  You could then join them back together with `do.call(rbind,results)` (depending on how you are separating the `u` and `c` results).